# How can I attach a 2x to a deck joist to give more room for stair stringer?

Tags: deck

I am attaching stairs to a deck coming perpendicular off of the joist.  To attach the stair stringers to the deck I need to add a 2x6 below the joist so the stair stringer hanger can attach to it.  I had seen [these](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Simpson-Strong-Tie-R-Tie-Plate-TP37/100375215#specifications) at home depot and wondered if I could attach the 2x6 to the 2x10 joist with a few of them, but they were not load rated.

What is the proper way to do this.  I do not have two posts directly behind the stairs that I can attach it too.

My other option is to do the deck stairs flush with the top, but then I am not sure how I'll make the railings going down the stairs.

Comment: My deck (I did not build it, so don't know if it's correct) uses a 2x16(-ish) bolted behind the joist.

Answer (score 1):

I attach the 2x6 right to the face of the 2x10 joist. With an 8" rise you will have 2.5" to attach it too.  I use alot of nails and a few ledgerlock lags. I also always double the outside joist. I never had an inspector question it. If the bottom your steps are firmly attached by burying posts the stairs can not fall down.